# How to fill Notes Attribute in Active Directory Groups?

Tags: powershell, server, active-directory, active-directory-group

I want to fill the notes of Active Directory Groups. I looked Microsoft Docs and I wrote the this code;

```
Set-ADGroup -Identity "CN=XXX,OU=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=local" -Info "HELLO"
```

But,there is an error and the Microsoft Docs tell us that Notes is equals to Info Attributes in AD. Please help me :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6FCK.png)

Comment: PLEASE, do not post images of code/errors/data. why? because you already have it as text ... and the images are often difficult to read. your red text on black is one example of a nearly unreadable image of text.

Comment: Okey Lee_Dailey. I'm new here :)

Comment: easy to read info will almost always get you better, faster, and more to-the-point help. [*grin*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set-ADGroup -Identity "CN=XXX,OU=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=local" -Replace @{info="HELLO"}
```

-Info does not work here because it matches to common parameters.

Comment: I have another question? can we use CN parameters(attribute) with -filter instead of using fullpath ?